# Using javascript in for loops of django

Tags: javascript, django

```css
<style>
    .gal-wrapper{
        position: relative;
    }
    .gal-img.active{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 30rem;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-inline: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="gal-wrapper">
            {% for i in img %}
            <figure class="gal-figure">
                <img src="{{i.image.url}}" alt="" id="img{{i.id}}" class="gal-img">
                <figcaption>Lorem ipsum, dolor.</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <script>
                const newBtn = document.querySelector(".gal-figure");
                newBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
                    const imgBtn = document.querySelector("#img{{i.id}}");
                    imgBtn.classList.toggle("active");
                })
            </script>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I want to increase the width of the image when clicked, as I'm not much comfortable with javascript I approached this method to get what I want. But is there a better code of javascript to achieve the same result?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to increase the width of an element using javascript; you take the same click function and change the width of the element.

```
newBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    const imgBtn = document.querySelector("#img{{i.id}}");
    imgBtn.style.width = "50%";
})
```

Comment: Please provide some useful insights into your answer, not just code.

Comment: This is the code to increase the width of an element using javascript as asked for in the post, that is all the insight there is to provide. You take the same click function and change the width of the element.

Comment: Yes, now add that to your answer and see how much better and insightful it gets.